# Why are spawned Pokemon's stats suddenly identical for 2 people?

Tags: pokemon-go

It seems that lately, if the same Pokemon is caught by 2 people, the Pokemon will have the same CP, IV and attacks. This has been happening since the last update.

Is this supposed to be happening? Our levels are 30 and 37, if it matters.

Answer (score 12):

If both players are at least level 30, they'll always catch the same wild spawns if they're in the same place at the same time.